# 'Microsoft.SharePoint.MailMessage' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: sharepoint, smtp, message-level-security

'Microsoft.SharePoint.MailMessage' is inaccessible due to its protection level

On this code:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = "myemail@xxxxx.edu";
mail.To = "myemail@xxxx.edu";
mail.Subject = "Testing Code";
mail.BodyText = what;
mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
Smtp.Send(mail, "smtp.xxxxx.edu");
```

How can remidy this? changes to web.config? Any way to circumvent in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is saying that MailMessage does not have public constructor. Most likely, it is for internal SharePoint use only.

Actually, in most cases in SharePoint you need to use **SPUtility.SendEmail** method to send mail with SharePoint. It is very simple:

```
SPUtility.SendEmail(SPContext.Current.Web, false, false, "myemail@xxxxx.edu", "Testing Code", what);
```

See MSDN for details on this method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms411989.aspx

If you need to send email under ordinary user accounts, you should use **SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivilegies** method to provide elevated privilegies.

Only disadvantage is that SPUtility does not support attachments. If you need attach some files to your letter, please use [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx).

I know a good post from Edwin Vriethoff, which provide detailed information about sending email with attachments, with default SharePoint SMTP settings (they are configured through Central Administration):
http://edwin.vriethoff.net/2007/10/02/how-to-send-an-e-mail-with-attachment-from-sharepoint/